# Вывод массива в виде строки

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
p:{param240:1,pwr_int:10.303000,pwr_ext:14.554000,param23:111,param199:202}
```

Как его записать в виде строки? То есть как отобразить его в приведённом выше виде?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, есть функции `serialize(array)`, `json_encode(array)` и их антонимы `unserialize(string)` и `json_decode(string)`. А можно это дело оформить и через foreach, зависит от вашей конкретной задачи (если, например, значения надо обработать перед записью в строку).

Comment: всё верно, только не serialize, а unserialize, это я про "антонимы" :)

Comment: Верно, спасибо).

Answer (score 1):

выше приведен не массив а json обьект

//перечислит одномерный массив в строку через запятую без ключей

```
$str = implode(',', $str);
```

//многомерный массив с ключами в формате php кода

```
$str = var_export($arr, true);
```

//быстрый вывод масива

```
print_r($arr);
```